# run a batch command on all files in folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, file-conversion

I am using Timidity to convert midi files to wav:

```
timidity in_file.mid -OrM -o out_file.wav
```

I would like to write a batch script to run this command on a bunch of files which are organized in folders and subfolders. The output file (out_file.wav) should have the same name as the input file with the .wav extension. How can I do it? The midi folder is not the same as the timidity folder.

EDIT: so far I came up with this code:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b "D.\midi_path\*.mid"') do timidity %%f -OrM -o out.wav
```

How can I replace out.wav with the name of the input file (%%f) with the correct extension?

Comment: Read about [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and [for variable modifers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), supply the path to `x:\path\to\timidity.exe`

Comment: modifiers? `for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b "D:\midi_path\*.mid"') do timidity "%%f" -OrM -o "%%~dpnF.wav"`